# QRegExp : search a pattern that does not contain another pattern

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I am trying to search the following pattern :
`<b>.+</b>$`

But this pattern must not contain a `<b>` tag.

Given the following example:
`abba <b>acba</b> <b>adba</b>`

If I use the previous pattern, the result is :
`<b>acba</b> <b>adba</b>`

But the good result, which I want is :
`<b>adba</b>`

Because I want disallow a `<b>` tag between the two `<b>` and `</b>` border tags.

So, how can I do that?

I use QRegExp and I code in c++ language.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Floréal.

Comment: Your example does only contain two open/close pairs. Not one open/close pair within another open/close pair. Did I misunterstand something or is there something wrong with the example?

Comment: Mandatory read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/214671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See : `QRegExp::setMinimal ( bool minimal )`

Just set the QRegExp setMinimal property to true. E.g. :

```
QRegExp regExp;
regExp.setMiminal(true);
// use your reg exp
```

This will resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a not flag:

```
QRegExp rx("\\<b\\>[^\\<b\\>]+\\</b\\>");
```